# Could an attacker connect to a SSTP VPN if they know a users credentials but do not have the public certificate?

Tags: certificates, vpn

When setting up a SSTP VPN we distributed certificates to the trusted root authority of each client computer to validate the server, can this certificate also prevent attacks if credentials are lost?

e.g.
Can an attacker connect to our SSTP VPN if they do not have access to this certificate but do have user credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An attacker can configure VPN client to ignore certificate errors and successfully connect to VPN. Server certificate validation occurs on client and server has no idea how client validates it.